# Problem to create .MSIX package with Advance Installer 19.2

Tags: dll, signtool, advanced-installer, msix, microsoft-store

I want to publish my application in the microsoft store and I have seen that one of the easiest mechanisms is to package it in a .msix package, I am using Advance Installer 19.2, I have a build that generates an installer .exe that works perfectly, but instead the build that generates the .msix, I have the following problem.

The problem comes when I try to incorporate some third party .dll as for example api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll.

The message I get is:

```
ERROR: Invalid Portable Executable (PE) file. 'C:\...\api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll' is not a valid Portable Executable for the build: 'Build_MSIX_APPX->x64'. Please select a different one.
```

I have noticed that if I try to sign this .dll with signtool it doesn't let me either, getting the error

```
Done Adding Additional Store
SignTool Error: SignedCode::Sign returned error: 0x800700C1
For more information, please see https://aka.ms/badexeformat
SignTool Error: An error occurred while attempting to sign: C:\api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll

Number of errors: 1
```

The signature, I know it works because the rest of .dll both own and third party I can sign them well, the curious thing is that I have not even marked to sign the .dll api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll advance installer, I do not know if the error can come from the .msix always sign all your .dll or something like that?

If anyone has had a similar problem I appreciate any help!

Thank you very much

Generate a .msix installer to upload my application to microsoft app store

Answer (score -1):

When you open your setup project in Advanced Installer there is a Digital Signatures view in Left Menu. Just try to exclude the "api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll" file from Files Configured for Signing list and see if this helps.